# How to make PageControl shows with 2 lines

Tags: swift

I want to make my PageControl shows with 2 lines if `pageControl.numberOfPages > 15`

[image]

I have searched all of function of `pageContro`, but did not find any function could be handle this case. How to do this?

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't built-in. You'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: jtbandes have reason, it doesnt not exist, it's very ugly and it's a UX bad practise, when you had too many pages you can make  a control like: < (page number) >

Answer (score 3):

Since there's no built-in support, you have to implement it yourself. If you have that many pages, you should consider implementing something more like iBooks' page control:

[image: iBooks page control]

You can do this with a `UISlider` and couple of `UILabel`s. You can customize the appearance of `UISlider` by providing your own images. It's easy to find web tutorials about customizing `UISlider`'s appearance. Examples:

- http://www.alexanderbatalov.com/journal/2015/2/20/how-to-implement-custom-uislider-in-swift
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/32167/photoshop-tutorial-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uislider

Comment: This is a nice idea, you can always keep control to the deep level where you are +1

Answer (score 2):

Either use [@rob mayoff's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37223489/6277607) answer which i recommend or if your realy need to you could simply use 2 UIPageControl above each other.